# How to make a publicly accessible directory in a pc

Tags: port-forwarding, iis

I know this might be a pretty basic question, but I am quite stuck here. And I have very basic networking knowledge, if any. I have a PC with a static IP from my ISP. I connect through a wireless router (prolink H5004NK ADSL Wireless Modem) and my local IP is 192.168.1.6. I need to have a directory that has to be  publicly accessible by typing in my IP from anywhere. I don't need to host a website, just some files.
So far, I have created a virtual server in my router as follows:

[image]

the NAT mapping is as follows:

[image]

I also have a directory set up in IIS as follows:

[image]

But this does not seem to work. How can I fix this? Is the virtual server equivalent to port forwarding? What do you think is wrong here? please help!

PS: here is the screenshot from cmd for :

[image]

Comment: The NAT IP stuff is unnecessary unless you have multiple public IP addresses.

Comment: @DanielB I removed that.

Comment: Alright. The IIS settings look suspicious. I suggest you specify a wildcard binding.

Comment: Thanks for that, works with the default iis page. but with the firewall disabled

Comment: You'll have to open port 80 on the Windows Firewall as well.

Comment: The site is now accessible. @DanielB what did you say about iis settings looking suspicious? because I cant still get the files at my root folder. It is at e:\something. However the localhost default ppage is served when I type in the Ip from anywhere

Comment: that too is fixed, one more issue, I have elaborated in the comments in @sai chaitanya's answer. thanks everyone and happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NAT you have set up is a Source NAT - meaning your local IP(s) will be NATted when going out (so it does not matter for what you want to achieve). The Virtual Server should be fine - this will be a Destination NAT. For troubleshooting purposes I would shortly disable the firewall on your PC and then try to reach your Public IP on port 80. Before check if IIS is running and listening on all IPs with `netstat -an | findstr 80` (beware of Skype it uses port 80 if available). If you can get a response in your browser on `http://localhost`and see what you want to share then go to the next step and check the same with the Public IP instead of localhost. If it works with the firewall stopped - check your http firewall rule and allow it from Public and enable the firewall again (enable the FW no matter if it worked or not).

Comment: How can I check if IIS is listening to all ips? I did the netstat and this is what I got. But what is the ip under established? I dont even know it. I have added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: The `0:0:0:0` indicates All IPs for IPv4 and the `[::]` All IPv6. The IP under ESTABLISHED means there is a connection from your PC to the shown IP address. Have you checked if you can access `http://localhost` on your PC - does it show what you want to share?

Comment: I removed the site I added and disabled the firewall, now I can go to the defaullt iis page. What do i do from there? add a rule?

Comment: enable the firewall, allow Domain, Public, Private on the WWW HTTP Traffic In firewall rule (the rule should already be there). You did not mention how you got the default IIS page (localhost, private IP, public IP) - but all of them should work after the mentioned actions.

Comment: I used the public ip, will check the firewall settings now. i can't access when i've put it back on.

Comment: I set allow Domain, Public, Private to allow in windows firewall settings. it then says that the firewall is turned off. How can I do it for just WWW HTTP Traffic as you said? Sorry about the pestering, but I AM stuck. :) i cant find such a rule

Comment: I found it and works! thanks! Now I'll try to get me folder mapped to the iis.

Comment: I assume you are in the Control Panel Windows Firewall applet. Turn the firewall on for all Profiles. On the right hand side you have a Advanced Settings link (you can open this also by finding the Windows Firewall With Advanced Security shortcut). Under Inbound Rules find World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In), open it, check if it is enabled and on the advanced tab check the profiles (select all) - click ok - and this should allow you to get the IIS default page with the FW on using the Public IP.

Comment: Just saw your update :) - was typing a bit too much :D    I am glad that it works...

Comment: One more problem remaining, the directory where I want the files to be kept is at E:\somefolder. I need to point the website I made to go to that folder so that I can access files in that folder through http. (e.g. <myip>/abc.png) but I cant do this. I have pointed the directory as shown above. Why is this?

Comment: it seems all the requests go to the default site. Should I delete it?
PS: went ahead and deleted it, now it says cant find page. Looks like a permission issue.

Comment: Just changed the binding on my site to my local ip and everything is working fine. thank you so much. I know you must be celebrating new year somewhere in this world and wish that it would be the greatest new year for you!!! thanks again Zina...

Comment: DO not share the folder you want to publish on http. One of the correct ways to achieve what you want is to stop the default web site, create a new one, set the folder to your path and enable directory browsing, so you will be able to get the files through http. Maybe you will  have to add the MIME settings for the files hosted. You will see when you click on it if it will open or fire any action.

Comment: Thanks again, I set folder permission to view for everyone, enabled directory browsing and removed sharing. All fine now. thank youuuu, Zina the awesome!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a folder in the required directory (optional)

2. Right-click on the folder you want to share.
3. Select properties.

   a. Go to sharing tab.
4. In "Network file and folder sharing"

   a. click on "not shared."

   - In the text field- enter "Everyone" then click on ADD button.

   b. Then goto "Advanced sharing" enter share name if you want to.

   - click on "Permissions" slect the user and change values.
5. Click OK > OK > Close

Tada you are good to go.
The share directory is publicly accessible.

Comment: Not only is this a terrible idea, it is also not what the OP wants. He wants to set up port forwarding and IIS.

Comment: I had to share the folder to make it accesible, thanks for the suggestion. but I had to turn on network discovery. Is this bad? Is there any workaround to make the folder accesible without doing what is suggested in this answer, @DanielB ?

Comment: Here you can see the network path which can be accessed from other PC connected to your LAN. (In STEP 4)

Comment: I want to connect to this throough http through a public ip, not a lan

Comment: this might be useful: https://www.bitvise.com/file-sharing

Comment: @toing_toing Try using filezilla server so that you can the files anytime or webdrive [link](http://download.cnet.com/WebDrive/3000-2160_4-10017919.html). And for detailed information check this **Recommend** [link](http://www.practicallynetworked.com/howto/fileshare/fileshare_intro.htm)

Comment: I set folder permission to view for everyone and removed sharing and enabled directory browsing. All fine now. thank youuuu

Comment: saichaitanya and @DanielB  Happy new year